# Change the style of the react component based on its props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Header.js`:

```
const Header = () => {
 return (
  <header className="header">
    <Logo/>
    <HeaderMenu target="home-link"/>
  </header>);
}
```

and a `HeaderMenu.js`:

```
class HeaderMenu extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return(
        <nav className="header-menu">
            <a id="home-link">Home</a>
            <a id="project-link">Projects</a>
            <a id="blog-link">Blog</a>
            <a id="about-me-link">About Me</a>
        </nav>
    );
 }
}
```

How can I change an `a` elements style based on `target` props?
Example: if `target="home-link"`, then an `a` element with `id="home-link"` has its text underlined and another `a` element doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by applying a class to any element that you want to have styled differently. In your example of giving a different style to the link for the current page, you can iterate over your links and give an "active" class to the link whose id matches the target.

For Example:

```js
class HeaderMenu extends React.Component {
 render() {
    const { target } = this.props;

    const linkData = [
        {id: "home-link", title: "Home"},
        {id: "project-link", title: "Projects"},
        {id: "blog-link", title: "Blog"},
        {id: "about-me-link", title: "About Me"},
    ];
    const linkElements = linkNames.map(e => (
        <a id={ e.id } className={ e.id === target ? "active" : "" }>{ e.title }</a>
    ));

    return(
        <nav className="header-menu">
            { linkElements }
        </nav>
    );
 }
}
```

However if you use [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) (which you may want to do so the page doesn't refresh when a link is clicked) the `<NavLink>` component takes an `activeClassName` prop, which applies the given className any time the current location (url) matches the NavLink's `to` prop (which is analogous to the `a` tag's `href`).

Answer (score 0):

1. Save menu data into an `variable`.
2. Use `map` to add `a` tag
3. Set an `className = 'active'` on the `a` where target is matched.
4. then write css to add underline.

`HeaderMenu.js`

```
class HeaderMenu extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.menus = [
       { id: 'home-link', name: 'Home' },
       { id: 'project-link', name: 'Projests' },
       // ...
     ];
}

 render() {
    return(
        <nav className="header-menu">
            {
              this.menus.map(menu => (<a id={menu.id} className={this.props.target === menu.id ? 'active' : ''}>{menu.name}</a>))
            }
        </nav>
    );
 }
```

}

`css`:

```
.active {
   // text style when active
}
```